# Android Data Storage

Tags: java, android, database

Hi im building a project for college at the moment which is a Betting history app basically. It takes user input of different bet made and displays a summary of how much money the user has won/lost . What I am wondering is what would be the best way to store this information ??
Would I use a data base and SQLite or just use a simple text file to store the data?? I would want the total win/loss to be displayed at all times on the home screen of the app.

Comment: Personally I'd use a SQLite database.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 3):

You should use an [`SQLite` database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). It is easy to use, persistent, fast and does not need any additional permissions for your App.

Comment: And it might be easier to calculate the total win/loss from data stored in tables.